# Add ed25519 address to chain_spec.rs

Tags: substrate-node-template, nodes, substrate-node

Trying to add an ed25519 address to the chain_spec file.
The node_template has the defaults

```
vec![get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
```

We would like to add a custom address and we are using ed25519 and we can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> https://docs.rs/array-bytes/6.1.0/array_bytes/fn.hex_n_into_unchecked.html
> https://docs.rs/array-bytes/6.1.0/array_bytes/fn.hex2array_unchecked.html
>
> https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/50de15d8740a129db9c18a6698fbd183b00326a2/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L90-L176

```rs
let alice_hex_public_key = "..";
let alice: AccountId = array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked(alice_hex_public);
```